# Java Scanner not taking input from user

Tags: java

```
public class GameLogic {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void buyHouse(Player player, int propertyIndex) {
        boolean boughtHouse = false;
        GameboardSquare property = Board.getMonopolyBoard()[propertyIndex];
        int a = 0;
        if (property.getNumberHouse() <= 3) {
            System.out.println("How many houses you want to buy? it must be between 1-4: ");
            a = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong. Each time I run the code it doesn't let me input anything into the console, its just gets suck on the line `a = input.nextInt();`. I tried debugging it in the debugger but still don't know where its breaking this is my test case also

```
public class GameLogicTest extends TestCase {
    public void testBuyHouse() throws Exception {
        Player player = new Player(1000,0);
        GameboardSquare property = new GameboardSquare("Seb", 100,50,50,100,150,200,250,300,200,0,3,0,player,false);
        GameboardSquare[] gameboard = new GameboardSquare[1];
        gameboard[0] = property;
        GameLogic game = new GameLogic();
        Board board = new Board(gameboard);
        board.setMonopolyBoard(gameboard);
        game.buyHouse(player,0);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dovlc.png

also there should be a newline after the printout

Comment: Where do you run your code? In IDE or console? What exactly do you mean when you say `gets stuck` on the `a = input.nextInt();` line?

Comment: Looks like it is not stuck but waiting for your input at the place, you are running your code. Type whatever your input is and press enter. It should work!

Comment: Consider using System.console() to read input from a console.
And, depending on how you start this, a console might not be available or System.in not made available.

Comment: I run my code in the IDE and when I get to the input of the user it doesn't take anything in it just stops and waits and no input is passed it